# Placing data into specific bits

Tags: assembly, solaris, sparc

I am trying to learn SPARC and trying to create an array of size 4,000 bytes. Inside of this array I need to calculate an offset to place values in the correct location in that array. I think I know how to size the array, (just use .skip?) and I know how to calculate my offset, but can anyone tell me how to place the values into the correct byte?
Thanks everyone.
EDIT: I originally said bits, meant to say bytes.

Comment: I tried mov but I know that isn't right. I wasn't really sure how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Use read-modify-write and the proper bitwise operations (`AND` to clear a bit, `OR` to set a bit). If memory is not an issue, you could of course use one byte for each bit too.

**Update**: sample code illustrating how to clear a bit in the array. Setting a bit is similar, except instead of using `andn` it would use `or`.

```
! clear bit index %o0 in "array"
clrbit:
    mov %o0, %o1
    srl %o0, 3, %o0     ! byte offset
    and %o1, 7, %o1     ! bit offset
    set array, %o2      ! array base
    add %o2, %o0, %o0   ! byte address
    set 1, %o3          ! bit mask
    sll %o3, %o1, %o1   ! 1 << bit offset
    ldub [%o0], %o3     ! load byte
    andn %o3, %o1, %o3  ! mask off bit to clear
    stb %o3, [%o0]      ! write back
    retl
    nop
```

Oh, I see question has been updated to bytes instead of bits. Well, that's easier. Assuming index in `%o0`, data to write in `%o1`:

```
set array, %o2      ! array base address
add %o2, %o0, %o2   ! add byte offset
stb %o1, [%o2]      ! write byte
```

Comment: Suppose I wanted to clear data in byte 5... how would I go about this? and 5,"\n",5 gives an error...
Your help is much appreciated